# Cannot allocate memory dynamically in loop (a function eats all the memory)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, memory-alignment, declspec

When I run the code below, on the second iteration of the loop the whole OS hangs. If I open the task manager, it cleary shows that there's a huge memory leak. After I start the code execution, all the memory is gone in 4 seconds.

Here's the code:

```
void matrix_vector_multiplication_comparison()
{    
    for (unsigned DIMS_SIZE = 64; DIMS_SIZE <= 2048; DIMS_SIZE += 64)
    {

        __declspec(align(16))float* m1 = generate_random_1d_matrix(DIMS_SIZE * DIMS_SIZE);
        __declspec(align(16))float* m2 = generate_random_1d_matrix(DIMS_SIZE * DIMS_SIZE);
        __declspec(align(16))float* v1 = generate_random_1d_matrix(DIMS_SIZE);
        __declspec(align(32))float* v2 = generate_random_1d_matrix(DIMS_SIZE);
        __declspec(align(16))float* res1 = new float[DIMS_SIZE];
        __declspec(align(16))float* res2 = new float[DIMS_SIZE];
        __declspec(align(32))float* res3 = new float[DIMS_SIZE];


// ........ other stuff here...........

        delete[] m1;
        delete[] m2;
        delete[] v1;
        delete[] v2;
        delete[] res1;
        delete[] res2;
        delete[] res3;
    }
}
```

When I comment out everything in my code and leave only `__declspec(align())` declarations and `delete[]`'s inside my `for` loop, the memory leak is still there and it shows that the problem is actually with those `__declspec`s.

The functions `generate_random_1d_matrix`, `get_random_float` and `main` look like this:

```
float* generate_random_1d_matrix(unsigned const int dims)
{
    size_t i;
    float* result = new float[dims * dims];
    for (i = 0; i < dims * dims; ++i)
        result[i] = get_random_float(10, 100);
    return result;
}

inline float get_random_float(float min, float max)
{
    float f = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return min + f * (max - min);
}

int main()
{
    matrix_vector_multiplication_comparison();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Could anybody tell me what's going wrong here and how to solve that memory problem?

## Update

changed the code provided. I left only the parts that actually produce the problem.

Comment: Does it show that? If you remove the aligns, does the memory leak disappear? I would be very surprised if it did. What does the `generate_random_1d_matrix` do?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen If I remove `__declspec(align())` declarations and leave only `float* = ...` the memory still goes away. But if I comment out all the `__declspec(align(16))float* m1 =`, everything starts working fine

Comment: My suspicion is that generate_random_1d_matrix does not actually allocate with new[].

Comment: @EthanFine so could you tell me how I should make it work properly?

Comment: @EthanFine it's mine function, the code is in the question. I allocate the memore by `new`

Comment: Ok, its not the new[]. Can you tell me why you use declspec?

Comment: @EthanFine I use AVX and SSE, and they require the memory to be aligned 16 or 32 bits. But even if I remove declspec everywhere, the problems doesn't go away

Comment: Have you tried lowering 2048 to a more reasonable number? It could be you just can't allocate 10s of thousands of floats in large blocks at once.

Comment: Excuse me, not just 10s of thousands, far more than that. Dim_size is squared. Your trying to allocate millions of floats in large blocks.

Comment: @EthanFine well, even if I lower the `dims_size` to 128, it still hangs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try lowering 2048 to a more reasonable number. As it is you are trying to allocate millions of floats in large blocks, which doesn't seem reasonable. (It might actually be 10s of millions)

Even at just 128, you are trying to allocate 128^4*2 floats, which is over 200 million. I low balled a little in my previous explanation. even 64 is probably approaching too high.

I'm almost positive the problem is that in generate_random_1d_matrix when you use dims*dims you should be just using dims. Its a 1d matrix after all.

Comment: even if I lower the `DIMS_SIZE` to 128 instead of 2048, it still hangs

Comment: well, I actually must use 2048 in my function... any ideas how to make this possible?

Comment: I edited my post. I did my math wrong. You actually square dim_size TWICE. This is quadratic growth here. You're trying to allocate tens of millions even at just 64

Comment: Why do you need giant 1d matrices with millions of floats? If you can explain the purpose I might be able to help

Comment: it's for the sake of studying. This is actually the university task. With AVX such a big matrix can be multiplied by another one in like 1-2 seconds.

Comment: No, it can't. I think you misunderstood your assignment. 2048^4 = 17592186044416. That is the size of the matrices you claim to want to make.

Comment: it can actually. why it is squared? it is 2048^2

Comment: generate_random_1d_matrix(DIMS_SIZE * DIMS_SIZE) is the first squaring, new float[dims * dims] is the second squaring.

Comment: Man, here it is! THANKS, it was actually my mistake with squares! You're a lifesaver! If I remove the square in my `generate_1d_matrix` function, everything works perfectly even with 2048 sizes. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
delete[] m1, m2, v1, v2, res1, res2, res3;
```

This does not do what you think it does. You are using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), while you probably meant to pass multiple things to `delete[]`. You need to delete every variable on it's own:

```
delete[] m1;
delete[] m2;
delete[] v1;
delete[] v2;
delete[] res1;
delete[] res2;
delete[] res3;
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the tip, but this didn't change the situation. The memory still goes away rapidly

Comment: Now I left only the parts of code that actually produce the problem.